# Find corresponding object from js array and use its fields in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this JavaScript array:

```
Arr = [
  {
    a: {
      match: {
        urban: 1
      },
      threshold: 20,
      amount: 300,
      factor: 'impact_factor'
    },
    b: {
      match: {
        urban: 0
      },
      threshold: 30,
      amount: 100,
      factor: 'impact_factor_1'
    }
  },
  {
    c: {
      match: {
        family_type: 'solo_mayores'
      },
      threshold: 20,
      amount: 300,
      factor: 'impact_factor'
    },
    d: {
      match: {
        family_type: 'adultos_y_mayores'
      },
      threshold: 33,
      amount: 100,
      factor: 'impact_factor_1'
    },
    e1: {
      match: {
        family_type: 'bi-parental',
        urban: 1
      },
      threshold: 22,
      amount: 330,
      factor: 'impact_factor'
    },
    e2: {
      match: {
        family_type: 'bi-parental',
        urban: 0
      },
      threshold: 12,
      amount: 333,
      factor: 'impact_factor'
    },
    f: {
      match: {
        family_type: 'monoparental'
      },
      threshold: 14,
      amount: 310,
      factor: 'impact_factor'
    }
  }
]
```

And data looks like this in mongodb (a single row):

```
_id:5eecb9e406e5910084b07e54
uid:3529
weight:1
family_size:2
urban:1
family_type:"solo_mayores"
income_per_capita:35
impact_factor:0.005
factor_10-1:0.1
factor_1:1
factor_2:2
factor_3:3
factor_10:10
factor_urban_10_rural_1:10
factor_family_size:2
```

I would like to form a $project aggregation or similar aggregation to get a new variable using this logic:

newVariable = income_per_capita + X * amount1 + Y * amouont2,

where:

- X is a factor from Arr[0] (we should match an object from Arr[0] using match field and use the found object's factor)
- Y is also a factor from Arr[1] (we should match an object from Arr[1] using match field and use the object's factor)
- amount1 is an amount from an object from Arr[0]
- amount2 is an amount from an object from Arr[1]

How can I first find an object from array using **match** field and then use its fields in the $project to get new value?

**UPDATE**

Now I have this object:

```
var policies = {
    urban: [
      {
        id: 'a',
        name: 'urban',
        value: 0,
        threshold: 20,
        amount: 300,
        factor: 'impact_factor'
      },
      {
        id: 'b',
        name: 'urban',
        value: 1,
        threshold: 30,
        amount: 100,
        factor: 'factor_1'
      }
    ],
    family_type: [
      {
        id: 'c',
        name: 'family_type',
        value: 'solo_mayores',
        threshold: 20,
        amount: 300,
        factor: 'impact_factor'
      },
      {
        id: 'd',
        name: 'family_type',
        value: 'adultos_y_mayores',
        threshold: 33,
        amount: 100,
        factor: 'factor_1'
      },
      {
        id: 'e1',
        name: 'family_type',
        value: 'bi-parental',
        threshold: 22,
        amount: 330,
        factor: 'impact_factor'
      },
      {
        id: 'f',
        name: 'family_type',
        value: 'monoparental',
        threshold: 14,
        amount: 310,
        factor: 'impact_factor'
      }
    ]
  };
```

Then I made it work using this aggregation:

```
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "factor_1": 1,
      "impact_factor": 1,
      "urban": 1,
      "family_type": 1,
      "urban_": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "input": [
              {
                "id": "a",
                "name": "urban",
                "value": 0,
                "threshold": 20,
                "amount": 300,
                "factor": "impact_factor"
              },
              {
                "id": "b",
                "name": "urban",
                "value": 1,
                "threshold": 30,
                "amount": 100,
                "factor": "factor_1"
              }
            ]
          },
          "in": {
            "$setDifference": [
              {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$$input",
                  "as": "output",
                  "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                      {
                        "$eq": [
                          "$$output.value",
                          "$urban"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "amount": "$$output.amount",
                        "factor": "$$output.factor"
                      },
                      false
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              [
                false
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "family_type_": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "input": [
              {
                "id": "c",
                "name": "family_type",
                "value": "solo_mayores",
                "threshold": 20,
                "amount": 300,
                "factor": "impact_factor"
              },
              {
                "id": "d",
                "name": "family_type",
                "value": "adultos_y_mayores",
                "threshold": 33,
                "amount": 100,
                "factor": "factor_1"
              },
              {
                "id": "e1",
                "name": "family_type",
                "value": "bi-parental",
                "threshold": 22,
                "amount": 330,
                "factor": "impact_factor"
              },
              {
                "id": "f",
                "name": "family_type",
                "value": "monoparental",
                "threshold": 14,
                "amount": 310,
                "factor": "impact_factor"
              }
            ]
          },
          "in": {
            "$setDifference": [
              {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$$input",
                  "as": "output",
                  "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                      {
                        "$eq": [
                          "$$output.value",
                          "$family_type"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "amount": "$$output.amount",
                        "factor": "$$output.factor"
                      },
                      false
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              [
                false
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$urban"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$family_type"
  }
]
```

Which returns this:

```
[
    {
        "urban": 1,
        "family_type": "solo_mayores",
        "impact_factor": 0.005,
        "factor_1": 1,
        "urban_": [
            {
                "amount": 100,
                "factor": "factor_1"
            }
        ],
        "family_type_": [
            {
                "amount": 300,
                "factor": "impact_factor"
            }
        ]
    },
    ....
]
```

Now I would like to multiple $$output.amount by $document[$$output.factor].

How can I dynamically access mongodb document's fields based on the $$output.factor?

Comment: Could you please check updated question?

Comment: It would help if you could provide the input of your aggregation that provide your sample output. As of v4.2 there is no direct way to access `$document[$$output.factor]` so you could do `{ $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" }` and use `$filter` or `$reduce` on that array to find the value you are looking for

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This really helped!